# How to create a Broadcast receiver class inside Activity class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I am trying to Do similar to the below code in c# using an Activity to update the list of scanned Bluetooth devices from Broadcast receiver.

But I have my broadcast receiver as a separate class So I was not able to add the scanned devices on to the list.

Can you suggest me any better approach using c# xamarin.

I was trying to communicate to activity from a broadcast receiver

---

```
public class DeviceListFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener{
...
private final BroadcastReceiver bReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Create a new device item
            DeviceItem newDevice = new DeviceItem(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), "false");
            // Add it to our adapter
            mAdapter.add(newDevice);
        }
    }
};
```

}

### This my code which i tried.

namespace Launch
{

```
[Activity(Label = "Launch", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    string[] items;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothadapter;
    ListView listView;
    //BroadcastReceiver broadcast=null;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        items = new string[] { "wec","wce","dddsa","wecwe"};
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

listView = (ListView) FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.devices_lstv);

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1,items);
        listView.Adapter=arrayAdapter;


    RegisterReceiver(new BTimeReceiver(this), new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound));
    }



    class BTimeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        MainActivity activity;
        public BTimeReceiver(MainActivity activity) : base()
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            Toast.MakeText(context, "Received bluetooth device!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            BluetoothDevice device = (Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);

            Toast.MakeText(context, device.Name, ToastLength.Short).Show();

            // access your service via the "service" var...
        }
    }

}
```

}

---

This is the error from the beginning

Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5595308ae13c09d60df4f8b95233e7c94.MainActivity_BTimeReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/Launch.Launch-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/Launch.Launch-1/lib/arm, /data/app/Launch.Launch-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Types.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00114] in <54816278eed9488eb28d3597fecd78f8>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (System.String classname) [0x00006] in <54816278eed9488eb28d3597fecd78f8>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods..ctor (System.Type declaringType) [0x00064] in <54816278eed9488eb28d3597fecd78f8>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetConstructorsForType (System.Type declaringType) [0x0002c] in <54816278eed9488eb28d3597fecd78f8>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00032] in <54816278eed9488eb28d3597fecd78f8>:0 
  at Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver..ctor () [0x00034] in :0 
  at Launch.MainActivity+BTimeReceiver..ctor (Launch.MainActivity mainActivity) [0x00000] in C:\Users\ACHINTAR\source\repos\Launch\Launch\MainActivity.cs:73 
  at Launch

Comment: Substitute your Activity for the Service in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924587/c-sharp-android-get-broadcast-receiver-on-a-service/41925912#41925912

Comment: Thank you,I tired But My activity is showing class not found error at the constructor of the broadcast receiver. @SushiHangover

Comment: Please post your error message.

Comment: Please make sure you didn't add the `[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]` attribute.

Comment: ok Sure @YorkShen-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

> **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ... on path: DexPathList**

This is a known issue in the creation of the Java `classes.zip` file :

- Bug: [xamarin.android_8.1/#Known_Issues](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.1/#Known_Issues)
- GitHub PR fix: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1142

#### Workaround:

You can **delete the bin&obj files of your project and clean/rebuild** as a workaround in order to recreate the Java `classes.zip` file.